# How can I display an api response with Spring and Vaadin in a grid?

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, vaadin-grid

I have been scratching my head trying to figure this out. Currently I am calling a get request from an api.

```
    public class SerialsService {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public SerialsService(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        webClient = builder.baseUrl("https://api.skulabs.com").build();
    }

    public List<SerialRoot> getSerialNums() {
        return (List<SerialRoot>) webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/order/get_scanned_serial_numbers?start=2021-11-29T00:00:00Z&end=%s".formatted(date))
                .header(auth, skuT + token)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(SerialRoot.class)
                .block();
    }
}
```

I have pojo set up, where I have a root class, and the object class.

```
public class SerialRoot {

    @JsonProperty("serial_numbers")
    public ArrayList<SerialNumbers> getSerial_numbers() {
        return this.serial_numbers; }
    public void setSerial_numbers(ArrayList<SerialNumbers> serial_numbers) {
        this.serial_numbers = serial_numbers; }
    ArrayList<SerialNumbers> serial_numbers;

}
```

```
public class SerialNumbers {
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public String get_id() {
        return this._id; }
    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id; }
    String _id;

    @JsonProperty("store_id")
    public String getStore_id() {
        return this.store_id; }
    public void setStore_id(String store_id) {
        this.store_id = store_id; }
    String store_id;

    @JsonProperty("order_number")
    public String getOrder_number() {
        return this.order_number; }
    public void setOrder_number(String order_number) {
        this.order_number = order_number; }
    String order_number;

    @JsonProperty("item_id")
    public String getItem_id() {
        return this.item_id; }
    public void setItem_id(String item_id) {

        if (item_id.equalsIgnoreCase("62cef3ea62c214aa81912cdc"))
        {
            this.item_id = "Product 1";
        } else if (item_id.equalsIgnoreCase("62cef3ea62c214aa81912cdc")
                && getVariant_id() == "42132807549149") {
            this.item_id = "Product 2";
        }

        //this.item_id = item_id;
        }

    String item_id;

    @JsonProperty("time")
    public Date getTime() {
        return this.time; }
    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time; }
    Date time;

    @JsonProperty("serial_number")
    public String getSerial_number() {
        return this.serial_number; }
    public void setSerial_number(String serial_number) {
        this.serial_number = serial_number; }
    String serial_number;

    @JsonProperty("listing_id")
    public String getListing_id() {
        return this.listing_id; }
    public void setListing_id(String listing_id) {
        this.listing_id = listing_id; }
    String listing_id;

    @JsonProperty("variant_id")
    public String getVariant_id() {
        return this.variant_id; }
    public void setVariant_id(String variant_id) {
        this.variant_id = variant_id; }
    String variant_id;
}
```

Using vaadin grid, how can I create a grid displaying where the columns show `serial_number`, `order_number`, `time` and `item_id` ? Everything I try either results in mapping errors, or shows completely blank.

Edit: I do want to note, I was able to display one row on the grid with the values im looking for, but this only displays one. Here is how that worked:

```
public OrderList(SerialsService service) {
        var gridSerial = new Grid<SerialRoot>(SerialRoot.class);

        gridSerial.setItems(service.getSerialRoot());

        add(gridSerial);

            gridSerial.setColumns();
        
        // Adding each key to the grid
            gridSerial.addColumn(serialRoot -> {
                SerialNumbers serialNumbers = serialRoot.getSerial_numbers().get(0);
                return serialNumbers.getOrder_number();
            }).setHeader("Order Number");

            gridSerial.addColumn(serialRoot -> {
                SerialNumbers serialNumbers = serialRoot.getSerial_numbers().get(0);
                return serialNumbers.getSerial_number();
            }).setHeader("Serial Number");

            gridSerial.addColumn(serialRoot -> {
                SerialNumbers serialNumbers = serialRoot.getSerial_numbers().get(0);
                return serialNumbers.getTime();
            }).setHeader("Date");

            gridSerial.addColumn(serialRoot -> {
                SerialNumbers serialNumbers = serialRoot.getSerial_numbers().get(0);
                return serialNumbers.getItem_id();
            }).setHeader("Item Model");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. I was making it more complicated than it needed to be.

```
public OrderList(SerialsService service) {
        TextField searchField = new TextField();
            searchField.setPlaceholder("Search Serial");
            searchField.setPrefixComponent(new Icon("lumo", "search"));
            searchField.setTooltipText("Enter a serial number");


        add(searchField);
        Grid<SerialNumbers> gridTest = new Grid<>(SerialNumbers.class);

        gridTest.setColumns();

        gridTest.addColumn(SerialNumbers::getItem_id)
                .setSortable(true)
                .setHeader("Item ID");

        gridTest.addColumn(SerialNumbers::getOrder_number)
                .setSortable(true)
                .setHeader("Order Number");

        gridTest.addColumn(SerialNumbers::getSerial_number)
                .setSortable(true)
                .setHeader("Serial Number");

        gridTest.addColumn(SerialNumbers::getTime)
                .setSortable(true)
                .setHeader("Time");


        gridTest.setItems(service.getSerial().getSerial_numbers());
        add(gridTest);

    }
```

I will convert this into a dto since I actually have more than one response from different endpoints and will get select values needed.